# Android elements chopped off when using horizontal linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, element

I'm using the LinearLayout to display a few ImageButtons. Basically what I intend to do is give a specific fixed size to each ImageButton and then acc to the screen size the number of ImageButtons should be displayed in a row. Ideally, on a cell phone just 2 ImageButtons in a row.

But when using the LinearLayout, what's happening is that instead of moving the extra ImageButtons that can't fit on one row to the next row, the ImageButtons are chopped of.

Here's the code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="What are you interested in?"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/education"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use weight for each and every imageview

Answer (score 0):

copy this code and try it

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="What are you interested in?" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5px"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/icon" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tried, but it shows all four ImageButtons on the same line by squeezing them in somehow, doesn't really look pretty.

Comment: Thanks alot for putting efforts and helping out though..@Anand Savjani ...Is there anything else you'd suggest ?

Comment: Reduce height of images

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout doesn't wrap things from one line to another.  I don't think there's one provided with the SDK that does that, though I'm sure there are some 3rd party ones.

You have several choices.

1. Just put fewer of them per row (you'll need a separate LinearLayout for each row).
2. Build the rows at run time instead of declaring them statically in XML.  It's a little trickier but you can create each button in code and then decide if it will fit or not in the current row.  If not, you create a new LinearLayout and add that to the overall layout.
3. You can create your own layout.  This isn't as hard as it may seem.  The work takes place essentially in two methods: onMeasure() and onLayout().

By the way, I think you may have some incidental problems because you are incorporating tags from RelativeLayout (e.g. android:layout_alignParentTop="true") which are irrelevant to LinearLayout.  Also, for LinearLayout, be sure to specify the orientation.

Here's a little sketch of code (I've left out params but this will give you a model to follow):

```
LinearLayout outerLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById (R.id.outer_layout);
LinearLayout rowLayout = null;
int rowWidth = 0;
int screenWidth = get screen width;
for (int i = 0;  i < buttonCount;  i++)
{
  ImageButton b = new ImageButton();
  b.setText();  b.... // other attributes;

  // add to current row
  if (rowLayout != null)
    if (b.getIntrinsicWidth() + rowWidth > screenWidth)
      rowLayout = null;
  if (rowLayout == null)
  {
    rowLayout = new LinearLayout();
    outerLayout.add (rowLayout);
  }
  rowLayout.add (b);
  rowWidth += b.getIntrinsicWidth();
}
```

It is tricky to get sizes of things before they are actually laid out.  In other words, you can't create a button and then use getWidth().  It will return 0.  getIntrinsicWidth() I believe will work but will not include margins or other adjustments you may want.  So you have to add those in by hand.

Alternatively, it is possible to render elements to a bitmap and then get their dimensions.  In your case, the first way is probably easier and adequate.

I've left out some parameters here and there to be expedient.  Too much code to write :)

Comment: It'll be interesting to see how option 2 would be implemented, not sure about it at this point..Could you please elaborate on that ? Option 1 i've kept as a last resort, though I wanna avoid that since even for bigger screens like tablet, it'll just show like 2 buttons

Comment: I added some almost-real code.  Hopefully it will give you an idea.

Comment: No luck so far, haven't tried adding components dynamically before so having some issues.. Will share the code soon. @PeriHartman